# FSCalendar is unable to detect

Tags: ios, fscalendar

I am using FSCalendar. Installed its Pod. but its not working. In IB I am getting strange error which says

> storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for CalendarViewController (RTc-Y3-fKa): dlopen(FSCalendar.framework, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       FSCalendar.framework: required code signature missing for 'FSCalendar.framework'

and similarly when i wanted to use it in My ViewController, so it throws error over this

import UIKit

class CalendarViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, FSCalendarDataSource, FSCalendarDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

> so getting error on FSCalendarDataSource, FSCalendarDelegate, and error is Use of undeclared type 'FSCalendarDataSource' and similarly for delegate.

I do not know what is the problem whereas I have installed the pods multiple times but this did not work for me. Did anyone face this issue. 
Please help

**P.S = I am using xcode 9.2 and mac mini 2014 version 10.12.6**

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup a bridging header for this?

Relevant instructions for FSCalendar can be [found here](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar#or-swift).

The pod is written in Objective-C, but your posted code is in Swift. That means you need a bridging header set up to allow a Swift project to talk to Objective-C code.

The follow link discusses how to set up a bridging header.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: what kind of briding header?

Comment: I am new to android please let me know

Comment: @Androidteem Added a link

Comment: i did same as you said. But still the errors are there

Comment: and I am even unable to see my whole design of that viewcontroller in IB . but still app is able to run on simulator